# UIAlert Message Increment

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

This seems easy but i can not wrap my head around it.

I have the UIAlertView init here:

```
- (IBAction)countClick:(id)sender {

    NSInteger *num = 1;
    self.alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",num];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.alertMessage);
    self.countAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Count" message:self.alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"end" otherButtonTitles:@"+",@"-", nil];
    [self.countAlert show];
}
```

When this view is shown it has three buttons a title and the message.
My problem is when they click the + Button or the - Button i need the Message to decrease or add and then reflect it.

I cant seem to get that to work, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't do this with a `UIAlertView`. Once displayed, the message can't be updated unless you dismiss the current alert and display another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `UIAlertView`. You have to create your own custom alert to handle this kind of functionality.